# Mongo - constraints on a compound index vs. a prefix

Tags: mongodb

[From the Mongo docs:](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/index-compound/#prefixes)

> If you have a collection that has both a compound index and an index on its prefix (e.g. { a: 1, b: 1 } and
>   { a: 1 }), **if neither index has a sparse or unique constraint, then you can remove the index on the prefix** (e.g. {
>   a: 1 }). MongoDB will use the compound index in all of the situations that it would have used the prefix index.

How do the constraints make a difference?

Comment: TBH this depends on scenario. Unique and sparse constraints actually change the formation and contents of the index as such, `{a:1,b:1}, {sparse: true}` is not redundant for `{a:1}` when fulfilling `db.c.find({a:1, b:1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best explained through examples of contradiction.

1) Let's say you have a sparse compound index `{a, b}` and a regular index `{a}`, then the document

```
{ a : null, foo : "bar" }
```

would not be part of the sparse index, but it is indexed in the regular `{a}` index. Hence, documents with `{ a : null }` can't be found using the sparse index, but they can be found using the regular one (as a side note, if many such documents exist the tree becomes unbalanced and slow).

2) Let's say you have a compound `{a, b}` index and a unique `{a}` index, then the following two documents would violate the unique constraint of the `{a}` index, but not the compound index, even if you converted it to a unique index:

```
{ a : 1, b : 1 }
{ a : 1, b : 2 }  // the {a,b} tuple is different, but a isn't unique
```

Hence, the existence or non-existence of a unique `a` index determines whether the second document can be inserted at all.

3) Likewise, the uniqueness of the `{a, b}` tuple doesn't imply uniqueness of `a` alone, and so forth. You can find contradictions to all combinations, unless both indexes are neither sparse nor have a unique constraint.

Comment: don't agree with 3) what if i have unique index on {a,b} but not on {a} and i removed {a} how will it effect ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. If you don't have an index on `a` but on `{a, b}` and you remove `{a}` (I guess you mean something like "remove all fields called `a` from the documents in the collection)", then all `{a, b}` tuples will be `{null, b}`. If the values of `b` aren't unique, the update of the `a` values will cause an error the first time it creates a non-unique tuple. You can easily verify or falsify what I said in a tiny collection, which simplifies the discussion a lot.

Comment: don't agree with 3) what if i have unique index on {a:1,b:1} but a non-unique index on {a:1} and i removed prefix index {a:1} how will it effect ? –
I cannot find a query that will ever use prefix index {a:1} only the prefix index don't need to be unique.

Comment: I agree with @ArunPratapSingh, statement (3) in this answer is overly broad (as is the wording quoted in the question from the original documentation). If the compound index `{a:1, b:1}` is unique, but the "shorter" index `{a:1}` is _not_ unique, there is no harm in removing `{a:1}`. No guarantees of uniqueness will be lost, and MongoDB can use a prefix of `{a:1, b:1}` for any query where it would have used `{a:1}`. If `{a:1}` were unique, it would not be safe to remove it regardless of the uniqueness of `{a:1, b:1}`.